# Why is the arduino ignoring a function call?

Tags: c++, debugging, arduino-uno

I am currently running this program on my arduino..

main.ino

```
#include "speed_profile.h"


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  output_pin_setup();
  cli();
  timer1_setup();
  sei();
}

void loop() 
{
      //int motor_steps = 23400;//-9600; //23400 -  100%
      // Accelration to use.
      //int motor_acceleration = 500;//500;
      // Deceleration to use.
      //int motor_deceleration = 500;//500;
      // Speed to use.
      //int motor_speed = 1000; // 1000
      init_tipper_position();
      compute_speed_profile(23400, 500, 500, 1000); 
}
```

and for some reason is not executing the `init_tipper_position`, which looks like this.

```
void init_tipper_position()
{
  digitalWrite(en_pin, HIGH);
  delay(1);

  digitalWrite(dir_pin, LOW);
  delay(1);


  while((PINB & (0 << 2)))  
  {
    digitalWrite(step_pin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(100);
    digitalWrite(step_pin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(100);

  }

  digitalWrite(en_pin, LOW);

}
```

I know that for certain it skips due to the following reasons.

1. 1) nothing happens on the hardware I am working on. Its suppose to
   move a move until a sensor gets activated, but that doesn't happen.
2. if enable pin was high, would it be impossible to move motor,
   which it is possible in this case
3. I have a logic analyser which,
   i can scope the output with, which shows that Enable isn't high.

So why is the program skipping that part the function. 
It should be noted that the function works, if I remove the function, under it from main.

All the function used in the code can be seen in the .cpp file. profile is just a struct that keeps track of some variables.

.cpp

```
#include "speed_profile.h"


volatile speed_profile profile;

ros::NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware, 1, 2, 125, 125> nh;
//ros::NodeHandle nh;

std_msgs::Int8 status_step_count;
std_msgs::Int8 status_tipper_availability;
ros::Publisher chatter_status("tipper_status", &status_step_count);
ros::Publisher chatter_availabilty("tipper_availability", &status_tipper_availability);

volatile bool global_state = false;
int received_data = 0;


void call_back_control( const std_msgs::Empty & msg)
{
  global_state = true;

  received_data  = (10 *23400.0)/100.0; // Converts input to motor_steps.
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub_control("tipper_control", &call_back_control );

void output_pin_setup()
{
  pinMode(en_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(step_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(slot_sensor_pin,INPUT_PULLUP);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(chatter_status);
  nh.advertise(chatter_availabilty);
  nh.subscribe(sub_control);
  //nh.subscribe(sub_command);
  profile.current_step_position = 0;
  delay(10);
  nh.getHardware()->setBaud(57600);
}

void init_tipper_position()
{
  digitalWrite(en_pin, HIGH);
  delay(1);

  digitalWrite(dir_pin, LOW);
  delay(1);


  while((PINB & (0 << 2)))  
  {
    digitalWrite(step_pin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(100);
    digitalWrite(step_pin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(100);

  }

  digitalWrite(en_pin, LOW);

}
void timer1_setup()
{
  // Tells what part of speed ramp we are in.
  profile.run_state = STOP;

  // Timer/Counter 1 in mode 4 CTC (Not running).
  TCCR1B = (1 << WGM12);

  // Timer/Counter 1 Output Compare A Match Interrupt enable.
  TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1A);
}

void compute_speed_profile(signed int motor_steps, unsigned int motor_accel, unsigned int motor_decel, unsigned int motor_speed)
{
  while (global_state == false)
  {
    //do nothing
    status_step_count.data = ((float)(profile.current_step_position / 23400.0)) * 100.0; //map(profile.current_step_position,0,23400,0,100); // could be expensive -- Nice flowing is only available with float
    status_tipper_availability.data = 1;

    chatter_status.publish( &status_step_count);
    chatter_availabilty.publish(&status_tipper_availability);
    nh.spinOnce();
  }

  digitalWrite(en_pin, HIGH);
  delay(1);

  signed int move_steps;

  if(received_data > profile.current_step_position) // Compares whether received percentage (converted to motor_steps) is greater or smaller than current_step_position.
  {
    profile.dir = CCW;
    //motor_steps = -motor_steps;
    move_steps =  profile.current_step_position - received_data;
    digitalWrite(dir_pin, HIGH);                          
  }
  else
  {
    profile.dir = CW;
    move_steps =  profile.current_step_position - received_data;
    digitalWrite(dir_pin, LOW);
  }

  delay(1);


  computation_of_speed_profile(move_steps, motor_accel, motor_decel, motor_speed); // Computes constants for profile.. 

  OCR1A = 10;
  // Set Timer/Counter to divide clock by 8
  TCCR1B |= ((0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (0 << CS10));


  while (global_state == true)
  { 
    status_step_count.data = ((float)(profile.current_step_position / 23400.0)) * 100.0; //map(profile.current_step_position,0,23400,0,100); 
    status_tipper_availability.data = 0;

    chatter_availabilty.publish(&status_tipper_availability);
    chatter_status.publish( &status_step_count);
    nh.spinOnce();
    //delay(100);
  }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  // Holds next delay period.
  unsigned int new_first_step_delay;

  // Remember the last step delay used when accelrating.
  static int last_accel_delay;

  // Counting steps when moving.
  static unsigned int step_count = 0;

  // Keep track of remainder from new_step-delay calculation to incrase accurancy
  static unsigned int rest = 0;
  OCR1A = profile.first_step_delay;
  switch (profile.run_state)
  {

    case STOP:
      step_count = 0;
      global_state = false;
      rest = 0;
      TCCR1B &= ~((1 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10)); // Stop the timer,  No clock source
      break;

    case ACCEL:
      PORTB ^= _BV(PB3);  // Toggles the step_pin
      step_count++;

      if (profile.dir == CCW)
      {
        profile.current_step_position++;
      }
      else
      {
        profile.current_step_position--;
      }  

      profile.accel_count++;
      new_first_step_delay = profile.first_step_delay - (((2 * (long)profile.first_step_delay) + rest) / (4 * profile.accel_count + 1));
      rest = ((2 * (long)profile.first_step_delay) + rest) % (4 * profile.accel_count + 1);

      // Chech if we should start decelration.
      if (step_count >= profile.decel_start)
      {
        profile.accel_count = profile.decel_length;
        profile.run_state = DECEL;
      }

      // Chech if we hitted max speed.
      else if (new_first_step_delay <= profile.min_time_delay)
      {
        last_accel_delay = new_first_step_delay;
        new_first_step_delay = profile.min_time_delay;
        rest = 0;
        profile.run_state = RUN;
      }
      break;
    case RUN:
      PORTB ^= _BV(PB3); // Toggles the step_pin
      step_count++;

      if (profile.dir == CCW)
      {
        profile.current_step_position++;
      }
      else
      {
        profile.current_step_position--;
      }  
      new_first_step_delay = profile.min_time_delay;
      // Chech if we should start decelration.
      if (step_count >= profile.decel_start)
      {
        profile.accel_count = profile.decel_length;
        // Start decelration with same delay as accel ended with.
        new_first_step_delay = last_accel_delay;
        profile.run_state = DECEL;
      }
      break;
    case DECEL:
      PORTB ^= _BV(PB3); // Toggles the step_pin
      step_count++;
      if (profile.dir == CCW)
      {
         profile.current_step_position++;
      }
      else
      {
        profile.current_step_position--;
      }  
      profile.accel_count++;
      new_first_step_delay = profile.first_step_delay - (((2 * (long)profile.first_step_delay) + rest) / (4 * profile.accel_count + 1));
      rest = ((2 * (long)profile.first_step_delay) + rest) % (4 * profile.accel_count + 1);
      // Check if we at last step

      if (profile.accel_count >= 0)
      {
        digitalWrite(en_pin, !digitalRead(en_pin));
        profile.run_state = STOP;
      }
      break;

  }

  profile.first_step_delay = new_first_step_delay;

}
```

.h file

```
/*
 * Contains the class concerning with calculating the proper speed profile 
 * for accelerating and decelerating the stepper motor.
 * 
 */

#ifndef speed_profile_h
#define speed_profile_h


#include <Arduino.h> 
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int8.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>

// Timer/Counter 1 running on 3,686MHz / 8 = 460,75kHz (2,17uS). (T1-FREQ 460750)
//#define T1_FREQ 460750
#define T1_FREQ 1382400

//! Number of (full)steps per round on stepper motor in use.
#define FSPR 1600

// Maths constants. To simplify maths when calculating in compute_speed_profile().
#define ALPHA (2*3.14159/FSPR)                    // 2*pi/spr
#define A_T_x100 ((long)(ALPHA*T1_FREQ*100))     // (ALPHA / T1_FREQ)*100
#define T1_FREQ_148 ((int)((T1_FREQ*0.676)/100)) // divided by 100 and scaled by 0.676
#define A_SQ (long)(ALPHA*2*10000000000)         // ALPHA*2*10000000000
#define A_x20000 (int)(ALPHA*20000)              // ALPHA*20000

// Speed ramp states
#define STOP  0
#define ACCEL 1
#define DECEL 2
#define RUN   3

// Pin numbering
#define en_pin 13
#define dir_pin 12
#define step_pin 11
#define slot_sensor_pin 10

// Motor direction 
#define CW  0
#define CCW 1

typedef struct 
{
  unsigned char run_state : 3; // Determining the state of the speed profile
  unsigned char dir: 1; // Determining the direction the motor has to move - Start being CCW 
  unsigned int first_step_delay; // Period time for the next timer_delay, determines the acceleration rate. 
  unsigned int decel_start; //  Determines at which step the deceleration should begin. 
  signed int decel_length; // Set the deceleration length
  signed int min_time_delay; //minium time required time_delay for achieving the wanted speed.
  signed int accel_count; // counter used when computing step_delay for acceleration/decelleration. 
  volatile signed int current_step_position; // contains the current step_position

}speed_profile;


void compute_speed_profile(signed int motor_steps, unsigned int motor_accel, unsigned int motor_decel, unsigned int motor_speed);
void computation_of_speed_profile(signed int motor_steps, unsigned int motor_accel, unsigned int motor_decel, unsigned int motor_speed);
void init_tipper_position();
void timer1_setup(void);
void output_pin_setup(void);
#endif
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while((PINB & (0 << 2)))
```

This is never true. 0 shifted any amount is always zero. Anything anded with zero is always zero, which is `false` so the loop is never entered.

Comment: it suppose to read int the sensor_value in the while loop.. even if change it 1 it does not work.